# How to use the concept of conditional classes in className when using mui v5 and styled components

Tags: material-ui

I'm aware that mui v5 is now using styled components but wanted to understand how to use the concept of conditional classes `className={clsx(isRed && classes.bar)}` when using styled components? How would the following example be best written with styled components?

**mui v4 example using `makeStyles`:**

```js
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  bar: {
    color: "red"
  }
});

export const Foo: React.FC<{ isRed?: boolean }> = ({ isRed }) => {
  const classes = useStyle();

  return <div className={clsx(isRed && classes.bar)}>Hello World</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a styled component:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

// this will generate classNames and will assign to the div
const MainContainer = styled("div")({
  position: "absolute",
  borderRadius: "*px",
  ....
});
```

create conditional style objects:

```
const fullScreen = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
};

const minScreen = {
  width: "30%",
  height: "40vh",
};
```

returned jsx

```
return (
    <MainContainer
      style={ifConditionTrue ? minScreen : fullScreen}
    >
      {children}
    </MainContainer>
  );
```

Comment: So inline styles are the only way to go?

Comment: @doberkofler I am not sure if it is the only way but it is a way

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you asked for this but you can do these kind of things with conditions.

```
const useStyle = makeStyles({
    departmentAddButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    maxHeight: 40,
    minHeight: 0,
    height: 33,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#404040",  },

  departmentAddButtonNoAbsolute: {
    maxHeight: 40,
    minHeight: 0,
    height: 55,
    width: 155,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
});
```

```
const foo = false;
```

```
    className={clsx({
                    [classes.userAddButton]: foo === true, 
                    [classes.departmentAddButton]: foo === false, 
                  })}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm looking for a solution on how to best translate conditional className's to the styled components used in mui v5?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, When I use a styled component, I write a base style for the component and do the conditional changes in Inline Style. I don't know if it's a good idea but works.

Comment: Sure that's a pretty good option but it has the general disadvantages of inline styles.